# Book/Article recommendation about modified gravity (scalar/tensor/scalar-tensor theories)

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, modified-gravity

Is there a book or article that discusses the modified gravity theories scalar/tensor/scalar-tensor (maybe others as well) theories? (Look at this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_general_relativity) for a general overview of the theories that I am talking about)

So, I am looking for a book that discusses these theories either in general or in detail. It does not have to include all of these theories, it could include some of them as well, but I am mostly interested in scalar/tensor/scalar-tensor.

I have found two articles:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.11098

https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2476

I am looking these type of articles

Comment: More on [modified gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modified-gravity+resource-recommendations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always find [Living Reviews in Relativity (LRR)](https://www.springer.com/journal/41114) a good place to start for these types of things.  Review articles tend to be very well referenced, so you can easily dig deeper into the literature when you find something interesting.

It doesn't look like there is a review specifically on alternatives to GR, but there are several reviews about tests of GR, which naturally discuss alternative theories.  Since these reviews give introductory overviews of the theories, much of the material is the same.  But I think it is still useful to get different authors' perspectives on which classes of theories are worth studying and why.

- Section 3 of [Cliff Will's review on experimental tests of GR](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2014-4#Sec3) discusses metric theories of gravity in general, including scalar-tensor (ST) theories.
- Section 2 of [the Yunes & Siemens review on GW tests of GR](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2013-9#Sec2) goes through several alternative theories, including ST.
- [Ishak's review on cosmological tests of GR](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41114-018-0017-4#Sec39) has a section on alternative theories relevant to cosmology, including ST theories and other theories with extra fields.
- Section 2 of [Gair et al's review on mHz band GW tests of GR](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2013-7#Sec2) introduces a slew of alternatives including ST, vector-tensor, and scalar-vector-tensor theories.
- This [Berti et al review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.07274) isn't an LRR, but it covers astrophysical tests of GR.  As is the theme, the first few sections give an overview of a whole bunch of alternative theories, including ST.
- Moving away from tests of GR, section 10 of [Felice & Tsujikawa's review on $f(R)$ gravity](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2010-3#Sec10) discusses how Brans-Dicke theory and ST more broadly appear as a special case of $f(R)$ gravity.